# AWS Compute Optimizer finding: Analyzing. This may take a moment

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am running EC2 Nodes. On the Management Console, I find the following message

```
AWS Compute Optimizer finding: Analyzing. This may take a moment
```

This message does not disappear. Even after days.

Additional Information:

- The IAM Role for the EC2 Instances include ComputeOptimizeReadOnly
- The EC2 Instances are part of an EKS-Deployment

Comment: Do you have IAM permissions to run it? Is SCP blocking it?

Comment: I receive results for EBS. I attached AWS Managed policies for ComputeOptimizeReadOnly to the EC2 instances